# XQuery - Output flat file

Tags: xml, xquery

XML on the input, flat file on the output - is that possible using **XQuery**?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. When you handle XML data, XQuery is an option.

Comment: Please, provide a complete example: a source XML file and the wanted result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XQuery has no specific constraints on its output. Depending on your parser, and its context, proper serialization might require some additional attention, like when you are running your XQuery through HTTP on an XML database.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a 3.0 processor then you can set your serialization mode to text mode.

```
declare namespace output = "http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization";
declare option output:method "text";
```

See http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-30/#id-serialization for how to configure serialization.

In text mode all the elements and attributes are stripped from your output, and only text content is written out.